# Handlebars precompiled templates not getting a name with Grunt.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, gruntjs

My Handlebars templates do not get names after compiling with Grunt.
This is my grunt task... When i console.log(Handlebars), the length of the templates property stays 1. And i can't call a template via Handlebars.template['name'] because it's always 'JST'.

```
handlebars: {
    compile: {
        files: {
            'inc/js/templates/templates.js': 'inc/js/templates/*.handlebars'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u get any solution??/

Comment: No, and i also don't recommend handlebars with grunt. I use Jade and AngularJS at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use the handlebars plugin for Grunt, and I would suggest that if you have to precompile HBS templates, use a static site generator like [Assemble](http://assemble.io/).

However, if you must use this plugin, I try reading through the [namespace documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars#namespace).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a namespace for the grunt task, like so:

```
handlebars: {
options: {
    namespace: 'mynamespace.Templates'
},
compile: {
    files: {
        'inc/js/templates/templates.js': 'inc/js/templates/*.handlebars'
    }
}
```

}